# Python pandas, stock portfolio value timeseries

Tags: python, django, pandas, data-science

I'm trying to build a time series consisting of the market value of my portfolio. The whole website is build on django framework. So the datasets will be dynamic.

I have a dataset named **dataset**, this dataset is containing stocks close price:

```
               YAR.OL     NHY.OL
date                             
2000-01-03         NaN  18.550200
2000-01-04         NaN  18.254101
2000-01-05         NaN  17.877100
2000-01-06         NaN  18.523300
2000-01-07         NaN  18.819500
...                ...        ...
2020-07-27  381.799988  26.350000
2020-07-28  382.399994  26.490000
2020-07-29  377.899994  26.389999
2020-07-30  372.000000  25.049999
2020-07-31  380.700012  25.420000
```

And I have a dataframe named **positions** consisting of the positions in a users portfolio:

```
         Date Direction  Ticker  Price  ...  FX-rate  Comission  Short  Cost-price
0  2020-07-27       Buy  YAR.OL  381.0  ...      1.0        0.0  False       381.0
1  2020-07-31      Sell  YAR.OL  380.0  ...      1.0        0.0  False      -380.0
2  2020-07-28       Buy  NHY.OL   26.5  ...      1.0        0.0  False        26.5
```

code for the postions dataset:

```
data = zip(date_list, direction_list ,ticker_list,price_list,new_volume_list,exchange_list,commision_list,short_list, cost_price_list)
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['Date','Direction','Ticker','Price','Volume','FX-rate','Comission','Short','Cost-price'])
```

Further, I have managed to split the postions dataset into one dataset for each ticker:

```
dataset = self.dataset_creator(n_ticker_list)
dataset.index = pd.to_datetime(dataset.index)
positions = self.get_all_positions(selected_portfolio)

        for ticker in n_ticker_list:
            s = positions.loc[positions['Ticker']==ticker]
            s = s.sort_values(by='Date')
            print(s)
```

This gives me:

```
         Date Direction  Ticker  Price  ...  FX-rate  Comission  Short  Cost-price
0  2020-07-27       Buy  YAR.OL  381.0  ...      1.0        0.0  False       381.0
1  2020-07-31      Sell  YAR.OL  380.0  ...      1.0        0.0  False      -380.0

[2 rows x 9 columns]
         Date Direction  Ticker  Price  ...  FX-rate  Comission  Short  Cost-price
2  2020-07-28       Buy  NHY.OL   26.5  ...      1.0        0.0  False        26.5
```

I have made this is excel, and the end goal is to create the yellow dataframe:

[image: Dataframe created in Excel]

Please note that this is dynamic, I have used two stocks and a lesser timeframe to make it easier to create, but it could just as easily be 10 stocks

Answer (score 3):

Overview / summary

- Keep one data frame for each 'concept' -- closing prices, positions, etc.
- Then multiply data frames (value = positions x price).
- Separate into multiple data frames for reporting.

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

# create data frame with closing prices
data = '''date YAR.OL NHY.OL
2020-07-27  381.799988  26.350000
2020-07-28  382.399994  26.490000
2020-07-29  377.899994  26.389999
2020-07-30  372.000000  25.049999
2020-07-31  380.700012  25.420000
'''
closing_prices = (pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), 
                             sep='\s+', engine='python', 
                             parse_dates=['date']
                            )
                  .set_index('date')
                  .sort_index()
                  .sort_index(axis=1)
                 )
print(closing_prices.round(2))

            NHY.OL  YAR.OL
date                      
2020-07-27   26.35   381.8
2020-07-28   26.49   382.4
2020-07-29   26.39   377.9
2020-07-30   25.05   372.0
2020-07-31   25.42   380.7
```

Now create positions (by typing in from the Excel screen shot).  I assumed each entry was buy or sell for that day.  Cumulative sum gives then-current positions.

```
positions = [
    ('YAR.OL', '2020-07-27',  1),
    ('YAR.OL', '2020-07-31', -1),
    ('NHY.OL', '2020-07-28',  1),
]
# changed cost_price to volume
positions = pd.DataFrame(positions, columns=['tickers', 'date', 'volume'])
positions['date'] = pd.to_datetime(positions['date'])

positions = (positions.pivot(index='date', columns='tickers', values='volume')
             .sort_index()
             .sort_index(axis=1)
            )
positions = positions.reindex( closing_prices.index ).fillna(0).cumsum()
print(positions)

tickers     NHY.OL  YAR.OL
date                      
2020-07-27     0.0     1.0  # <-- these are transaction volumes
2020-07-28     1.0     1.0
2020-07-29     1.0     1.0
2020-07-30     1.0     1.0
2020-07-31     1.0     0.0
```

Now, the portfolio value is positions times closing price.  There is one column for each stock.  And we can compute the sum for each day with 'sum(axis=1)'

```
port_value = positions * closing_prices
port_value['total'] = port_value.sum(axis=1)
print(port_value.round(2))

tickers     NHY.OL  YAR.OL   total
date                              
2020-07-27    0.00   381.8  381.80
2020-07-28   26.49   382.4  408.89
2020-07-29   26.39   377.9  404.29
2020-07-30   25.05   372.0  397.05
2020-07-31   25.42     0.0   25.42
```

UPDATE - suggestions for further work

1. Include traded price in the Positions data frame.
2. Also include trade timestamp in the Positions data frame.
3. The end-of-day portfolio value would use end-of-day prices.  Profit/loss also includes purchase/sale price.  Which do you want?
4. The data frame Index (and MultiIndex) along with broadcasting are relevant concepts for this application.

Comment: amazing, way to solve this. One problem/question, need to use the price and volume from the positions dataset. So when he bought the YAR.OL shares he actually paid 381, and when he bought NHY.OL he paid 26,5. How can make this into the code?

Comment: I added an Update section to the post, and changed 'cost_price' to 'volume' in the 'positions' data frame.

Comment: I'm trying to solve the cost-price part, but having a hard time. How will this work? Could you help me out with this part?

Comment: Maybe you have to change `pivot` by `pivot_table`