# Python, Pands, Stock portfolio rolling value timeseries issue

Tags: python, pandas, data-science, finance

I have created a timeseries in Python that calculates the rolling portfolio market value per given date. The timeseries looks like this for now (the total is the sum of NHY.OL and YAR.OL)

```
tickers     NHY.OL  YAR.OL   total
date                              
2020-07-27    0.00   763.60  763.60
2020-07-28   26.49   764.80  791.29
2020-07-29   26.39   755.80  782.19
2020-07-30   25.05   744.00  769.05
2020-07-31   25.42   380.70  406.12
```

This time series is built up by a positions table and a dataset containing the close price for the stocks, the positions table is dynamic, meaning it will gather its data from a Django model, where users can enter their holdings in their portfolio, therefor this dataset provided is a simple example to solve this issue I'm having.

*Postions table:*

```
         Date Direction  Ticker  Price  Volume  FX-rate  Comission  Short  Cost-price
0  2020-07-27       Buy  YAR.OL  381.0   2      1.0        0.0  False       381.0
1  2020-07-31      Sell  YAR.OL  380.0  -1      1.0        0.0  False      -380.0

[2 rows x 9 columns]
         Date Direction  Ticker  Price  Volume  FX-rate  Comission  Short  Cost-price
2  2020-07-28       Buy  NHY.OL   26.5   1      1.0        0.0  False        26.5
```

*The dataset for end of day stock prices:*

```
            NHY.OL  YAR.OL
date                      
2020-07-27   26.35   381.8
2020-07-28   26.49   382.4
2020-07-29   26.39   377.9
2020-07-30   25.05   372.0
2020-07-31   25.42   380.7
```

However, the initial price in the rolling portfolio value is wrong. For instance, on the 2020-07-27 the user paid 381 for the share he bought, so the market value should be 762. The portfolio value is not calculated by the buy price, but rather the market close price.

How can I fix this, so the final product looks more like this?

**How I want it to look:**

```
tickers     NHY.OL  YAR.OL   total
date                              
2020-07-27   0.00    762.0   762.0
2020-07-28   26.50   764.80  791.30
2020-07-29   26.39   755.80  782.19
2020-07-30   25.05   744.00  769.05
2020-07-31   25.42   380.70  406.12
```

A wonderful programmer here at StackOverflow helped me out with this code. The link to that thread: [Python pandas, stock portfolio value timeseries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63320488/python-pandas-stock-portfolio-value-timeseries/63321509?noredirect=1#comment111979291_63321509)

**The code**

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

# create data frame with closing prices
data = '''date YAR.OL NHY.OL
2020-07-27  381.799988  26.350000
2020-07-28  382.399994  26.490000
2020-07-29  377.899994  26.389999
2020-07-30  372.000000  25.049999
2020-07-31  380.700012  25.420000
'''
closing_prices = (pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), 
                             sep='\s+', engine='python', 
                             parse_dates=['date']
                            )
                  .set_index('date')
                  .sort_index()
                  .sort_index(axis=1)
                 )
print(closing_prices.round(2))
```

*Output:*

```
           NHY.OL  YAR.OL
date                      
2020-07-27   26.35   381.8
2020-07-28   26.49   382.4
2020-07-29   26.39   377.9
2020-07-30   25.05   372.0
2020-07-31   25.42   380.7
```

Defining the positions table:

```
positions = [
    ('YAR.OL', '2020-07-27',  2),
    ('YAR.OL', '2020-07-31', -1),
    ('NHY.OL', '2020-07-28',  1),
]
# changed cost_price to volume
positions = pd.DataFrame(positions, columns=['tickers', 'date', 'volume'])
positions['date'] = pd.to_datetime(positions['date'])

positions = (positions.pivot(index='date', columns='tickers', values='volume')
             .sort_index()
             .sort_index(axis=1)
            )
positions = positions.reindex( closing_prices.index ).fillna(0).cumsum()
print(positions)
```

*The output:*

```
tickers     NHY.OL  YAR.OL
    date                      
    2020-07-27     0.0     2.0  # <-- these are transaction volumes
    2020-07-28     1.0     2.0
    2020-07-29     1.0     2.0
    2020-07-30     1.0     2.0
    2020-07-31     1.0     1.0
```

Calculating the portfolio value:

```
port_value = positions * closing_prices
port_value['total'] = port_value.sum(axis=1)
print(port_value.round(2))
```

The final portfolio value as now:

```
tickers     NHY.OL  YAR.OL   total
date                              
2020-07-27    0.00   762.00  763.6
2020-07-28   26.49   764.80  791.29
2020-07-29   26.39   755.80  782.19
2020-07-30   25.05   744.00  769.05
2020-07-31   25.42   380.70  406.12
```

To sum up: The goal is that when a new position is added, the price used to calculate the market value at that time would be taken from the positions table price column.
Ex:

```
Date         Calculation comment     Calculation
2020-07-27 - Volume * Price paid     2 * 381
2020-07-28 - Volume * Market price   2* 282.4
....
If a user buys more shares of the same stock then for the day they bouth it, it would be: (New volume * prie paid)+(Previous volume * Market price)
....
Date          Calculation comment                                       Calculation
2020-07-29 - (New volume * prie paid)+(Previous volume * Market price) (1* 380) + (2 * 377.9)
2020-07-30 - Volume * Market price                                      3 * 372.0
```